# Ожидание закрытия

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как заставить элемент списка в котором есть менять фоновый цвет, после того как подменю исчезло? https://jsfiddle.net/b5uma4re/13/ Сейчас если навести и убирать указатель на дочерний элемент подменю, то фоновый цвет родительского элемента тоже пропадает. Нужно чтобы он пропадал после скрытия дочернего подменю.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $('.w1').hover(
        function(){
        $(this).find('.q1').stop(true, true).delay(500).slideDown();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.q1').stop(true, true).delay(500).slideUp();
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cont{
    font-size: 0;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.q1{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 165px;
    display: none;
}
.q1 li{
    border-top: 1px gray solid;
    display: block;
}
.w1{
    font-size: 16px;
    border-left: 1px black solid;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.w2{
    position: relative;
}
.w3{
    position: relative;
}
.q2, .q3{
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 210px;
    display: none;
}
li:hover{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cont">
     <li class="w1"><a href="#">Домой</a></li><!----------------------->
     <li class="w1"><a href="#">О нас +</a><!----------------------->
         <ul class="q1 fir"><li><a href="#">Наша история</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Как нас найти</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Час работы</a></li>
         </ul></li><!----------------------->
     <li class="w1"><a href="#">Наши товары +</a>
         <ul class="q1">
            <li class="w2"><a href="#">+ Штуковины</a>
                <ul class="q2">
                <li><a href="#">Простая штуковина</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Стандартная штуковина</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Продвинутая штуковина</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li class="w2"><a href="#">+ Гаджеты</a>
                <ul class="q2">
                <li><a href="#">Простой гаджет</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Стандартный гаджет</a></li>
                <li class="w3"><a href="#">+ Продвинутый гаджет</a>
                    <ul class="q3">
                     <li><a href="#">Продвинутый гаджет A</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Продвинутый гаджет Б</a></li>   
                    </ul></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#">Машини времени</a></li> 
         </ul></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё я решил: http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/13021/ оказалось просто.

```js
    $('.w1').hover(
        function(){
        $(this).find('.q1').stop(true, true).delay(500).slideDown();
        $(this).stop(true, true).css('background','red');
    },

    function(){
        if($(this).find('.q1').is(':visible')){

        $(this).find('.q1').stop(true, true).delay(500).slideUp(function(){
                   $(this).parent().stop(true, true).delay(0).animate(
                    {
                        backgroundColor:'transparent'
                    },0);
        });


    }
       else{
           $(this).find('.q1').stop(true, true).delay(300).slideUp();
            $(this).css('background','transparent');
       
       }
    });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cont{
    font-size: 0;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.q1{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 165px;
    display: none;
}
.q1 li{
    border-top: 1px gray solid;
    display: block;
}
.w1{
    font-size: 16px;
    border-left: 1px black solid;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.w2{
    position: relative;
}
.w3{
    position: relative;
}
.q2, .q3{
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 210px;
    display: none;
}
li:hover{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
     </script>
<ul class="cont">
     <li class="w1"><a href="#">Домой</a></li><!----------------------->
     <li class="w1"><a href="#">О нас +</a><!----------------------->
         <ul class="q1 fir"><li><a href="#">Наша история</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Как нас найти</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Час работы</a></li>
         </ul></li><!----------------------->
     <li class="w1"><a href="#">Наши товары +</a>
         <ul class="q1">
            <li class="w2"><a href="#">+ Штуковины</a>
                <ul class="q2">
                <li><a href="#">Простая штуковина</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Стандартная штуковина</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Продвинутая штуковина</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li class="w2"><a href="#">+ Гаджеты</a>
                <ul class="q2">
                <li><a href="#">Простой гаджет</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Стандартный гаджет</a></li>
                <li class="w3"><a href="#">+ Продвинутый гаджет</a>
                    <ul class="q3">
                     <li><a href="#">Продвинутый гаджет A</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Продвинутый гаджет Б</a></li>   
                    </ul></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#">Машини времени</a></li> 
         </ul></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению я не совсем понял, что вы хотите.

Как вам мой пример менюшки?

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.menu > li {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu > li:hover {
  background-color: #022;
  color: white;
}

.submenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  top: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #022;
  color: white;
  transform: translateX(-10px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.menu > li:hover .submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events:auto;
}

.submenu > li {
  padding: 10px;
}

.submenu > li:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Меню 1
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>Подменю 1</li>
      <li>Подменю 2</li>
      <li>Подменю 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Меню 2
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>Подменю 1</li>
      <li>Подменю 2</li>
      <li>Подменю 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Меню 3
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>Подменю 1</li>
      <li>Подменю 2</li>
      <li>Подменю 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Добавил решение через jquery.

```js
$('.menu > li').on('mouseenter', function() {
 const $this = $(this);
  if ($this.children('.submenu').length === 0) {
   $this.addClass('li-hover');
  } else {
   $this.addClass('li-hover');
   $this.children('.submenu').slideDown(300);
  }
}).on('mouseleave',function() {
 const $this = $(this);
  if ($this.children('.submenu').length === 0) {
   $this.removeClass('li-hover');
  } else {
   $this.children('.submenu').slideUp(300, function() {
     $this.removeClass('li-hover');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.menu > li {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.li-hover {
  background-color: #022;
  color: white;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  top: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #022;
  color: white;
  transform: translateX(-10px);
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.submenu > li {
  padding: 10px;
}

.submenu > li:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Меню 1
  </li>
  <li>Меню 2
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>Подменю 1</li>
      <li>Подменю 2</li>
      <li>Подменю 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Меню 3
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>Подменю 1</li>
      <li>Подменю 2</li>
      <li>Подменю 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Наведите на ссылку "О нас" и дождитесь появления подменю. проблема в том что если убрать указатель то ссылка "О нас" перестаёт быть красной. Нужно чтобы она переставала быть красной только после скрытия подменю.

Comment: Тогда используйте css решения для создания меню и регулируете скорость анимации через transition (вариант через css самый быстрый и легкий на мой взгляд) или же если нужен именно решение через jq, то в slideDown() и slideUp() можно задавать callback по завершению анимации, и в нем убирайте класс у кнопки "О нас"

Comment: Добавил для вас решение через jquery.

Comment: Ваше решение хорошее, но при добавлении метода delay() Остаётся проблема: https://jsfiddle.net/g60z9jxz/1/   фоновый цвет у "Меню2" и "Меню3" реагирует на указатель мыши не так как "Меню1" т.е. если навести и убрать на "Меню2" то цвет исчезает с задержкой

Comment: Используйте setTimeout вместо delay(), цвет исчезает задержкой, потому, что цвет убирается только когда slideUp() завершается. В моем решение цвет у элементов с потомками добавляется сразу и исчезает только когда подменю скрылось.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, ещё не изучал эту функцию, можете на этом примере её применить? https://jsfiddle.net/g60z9jxz/1/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52425/discussion-between-pegas-and-dimensi).